# How To Create a Walkthrough

Tags: ui

When you go to a page for the first time in SF a bubble pops up offering to walk you through all of the items on the page.

A colleague of mine said it was possible to create walk-throughs like this for new users to my ORG. I am having a heck of a time finding resources on how to create these walk-throughs.

Is this possible?
Where can I find information on how to create walk-throughs?

Comment: Do you want to create walkthrough for standard pages?

Comment: Maybe of help, check out walkme app. It will help to provide step by step on demand process instructions.....Just in case it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try [Whatfix](https://whatfix.com?utm_source=sf_stackexchange&utm_medium=referral_se_16&utm_campaign=se_answer_gokul&utm_content=se_answers_link&utm_term=SE_16). It is a interactive guidance and engagement platform which allows users to create and embed [interactive walkthroughs](http://academy.whatfix.com/interactive-walkthroughs/) in different formats. And as a matter of fact, Whatfix works with a lot of clients who use Enterprise softwares like Salesforce, Oracle CRM, MS Dynamics, ServiceNow, etc.[image: Here's a GIF of how it shows up on Salesforce]

Whatfix's interactive walkthroughs work similar to Salesforce's own walkthroughs but are more flexible and easy to create. And has an array of useful features.

Disclosure - I work at Whatfix.

Answer (score 2):

At one point in time, let's say about 15+ years or so ago, these would likely have been done using layers and DHTML 4.1. which could also be manipulated using javascript and later jQuery (the latter didn't exist at the time). At other times, I believe they were also done using Flash or what once was Macromedia Director. I'm not certain what Adobe has integrated those features into its product line at this point, but I believe it's referred to as Flex Builder, but they may have since renamed it. Today, with html5, one could do it in a variety of ways.

However, if you're trying to do it over top of Standard Pages, I think you might need to use the [Adobe Flash Builder for Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Adobe_Flash_Builder_for_Force.com_FAQ) because you wouldn't be able to add JS or jQ to those page, but *might* be able to run the plug-in on those pages. Unfortunately, the link to the actual download page seems to be broken, so I've linked to the FAQ page instead. Regardless, I'm fairly confident that Salesforce builds theirs using Flash and ActionScripts from within the latest builder. I believe this product used to be referred to as Adobe Flex builder, but they may have changed the name. More info and the link to a video on it can able be seen at [Building Rich Cloud Applications with Force.com and Flex](http://www.jamesward.com/2009/09/01/building-rich-cloud-applications-with-force-com-and-flex/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post by [Galen King](http://galenking.com/post/49426435422/a-roundup-of-jquery-walkthroughfeature-tour) that references several solutions

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know walkthroughs are created for you by salesforce and their blog here says "... and more are on their way", not sure if you can create your own custom walkthrough to train your users ( would be super cool if you can instead of creating training docs)

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_walkthroughs.htm

Go to the above link and click on the links to step through some predefined walkthroughs

**CAUTION:Keep in mind that walkthroughs guide you through your own Salesforce account, so you’re actually making changes to the data in your organization as you walk through the steps. If you’re concerned about making these changes, follow the walkthrough in a sandbox account or other test environment first.**